# Open spreadsheet using google-sheets-api

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to open a spreadsheet using only Google Sheets API from a web application? I want to do this so that only authenticated users on this web application can view this spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .NET, refer to this [.NET quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet).

> To run this quickstart, you'll need:
>
> - Visual Studio 2013 or later.
> - Access to the internet and a web browser.
> - A Google account.

And to set the properties of a sheet, you can start from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet).

> The Sheets API allows you to create sheets, delete sheets, and control
>   their properties. The examples on this page illustrate how some common
>   sheet operations can be achieved with the API.
>
> In these examples, the placeholders ***spreadsheetId*** and
>   ***sheetId*** are used to indicate where you would provide those IDs. The [spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id) can be discovered from the spreadsheet URL;
>   the sheet ID can be obtained from the [spreadsheet.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) method.